# Oracle view logic or performance tuning on case expression

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, indexing, sqlperformance

I have written a view logic to extract the data based on the requirement.
I need the suggestion or solution to improve the performance of the view logic.

**MYTABLE:**

```
|SID | SREF     |  STYPE  |  SQID  | SNAME | CCID1 | CCID2 | CCID3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|XX  | SREF001  |  HR     |  1     | 10001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|XX  | SREF001  |  HR     |  2     | 10001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|XX  | SREF002  |  KR     |  1     | 10001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|XX  | SREF002  |  KR     |  2     | 10001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|YY  | SREF011  |  HR     |  1     | 20001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|YY  | SREF011  |  HR     |  2     | 20001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|YY  | SREF012  |  KR     |  1     | 20001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
|YY  | SREF012  |  KR     |  2     | 20001 | ABC   | DEF   | XYZ   |
```

**MYVIEW:**

```
CREATE VIEW MYTAB_VIEW AS
SELECT SID, SREF,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=1 THEN SNAME END) AS HR1_SNAME,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID1 END) AS HR1_CCID1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID2 END) AS HR1_CCID2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID3 END) AS HR1_CCID3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=2 THEN SNAME END) AS HR2_SNAME,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID1 END) AS HR2_CCID1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID2 END) AS HR2_CCID2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='HR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID3 END) AS HR2_CCID3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=1 THEN SNAME END) AS KR1_SNAME,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID1 END) AS KR1_CCID1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID2 END) AS KR1_CCID2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=1 THEN CCID3 END) AS KR1_CCID3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=2 THEN SNAME END) AS KR2_SNAME,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID1 END) AS KR2_CCID1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID2 END) AS KR2_CCID2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STYPE='KR' AND SQID=2 THEN CCID3 END) AS KR2_CCID3
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY SID, SREF;
```

"MYTABLE" would have records in millions.
So, view logic became the biggest performance hit in the production.
I have the Indexes for STYPE, SQID, SNAME, CCID1, CCID2, CCID3. But it is still slow...

Execution time taking 105 Seconds, now!!

Please suggest me that how can I improve the performance...

Update: kindly don't suggest `MaterializedView`.

Thanks!

Comment: Your table needs to select & group the whole table (or whole index at best if it's covering). That's going to be expensive whatever you do, unless you "bake" it one way or another. Did you check if the index is even used? (Doesn't look  very likely if it's not covering.)

Comment: Yes! :( index is not used...

Comment: there is a `sqlldr` to process the records into table. So, the view is the matter here.. am totally blank out after checking the response time...

Comment: Then it's doing a full scan, and there's no avoiding that. The only way to get an index-only scan is if all the required columns are in the index. If the index-only scan is still too slow, the only way to go faster is to pre-calculate - I doubt the max/case parts are what slows this down if you have large volumes of data, the I/O is probably much more expensive.

Comment: Makes sense, I cannot even create the functional-index for `MAX` function as it require group-by..